# Send "relative to timezone" date by email

Tags: php, email, time

is there any way to send an HtML email (PHP) which will contain (in its message body) a timestamp with time zone, and the client which receive the email will see it other format and the date/time will be displayed relative to him/here.

From example, the server will send this date `2015-06-30T21:00:00+00:00` and the client which will receive the email will see its formatted according to his/here time zone to something like this:  Jun 6, 2015 21:00. **Note** that users with different time zone will receive this email and the date and time they will see will be according to their time zone.

Comment: your only practical choice is javascsript, and even then it's unlikely to work as JS-in-email is a major security+privacy vulnerability.

Comment: yea, no java script for gmail and other big email providers

Comment: When your user signs up get their timezone, store it, and format the date when you generate the email.

Comment: no JS in pretty much any mail client, period.

Comment: No, the email client will not mess with the email body.  Two possibilities, you could work out the local time based on the users local timezone (if you have that) and dynamically generate each email.  Or you could use some sort of image link, then serverside do a bit of geo ip timezone guessing to generate the image with the correct time.